# MagicalRecord defaultContext intermittently becomes nil

Tags: objective-c, ios7.1, magicalrecord-2.2

I'm using MagicalRecord throughout my iPad app;  I have a line of code, that *intermittently* throws an exception:

> +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name...

which I understand is because the NSManagedObjectContext is *nil*.  The app runs for quite a while until the error is triggered by this line of code and others similiar to it (using different entities):

```
    [apptDataArray addObjectsFromArray:[AppointmentInfo MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate]];
```

The NSManagedObjectContext is defined in AppDelegate.h as

```
NSManagedObjectContext *defaultContext;
```

and further in AppDelegate.m as

```
    defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
```

where it is used throughout the app. In a different SO question I had asked, Saul Mora said this:

> By creating a new context every time you save, and not re-using the context, you will guarantee to not cross threads, and to not crash your app 1% of the time.

Could it be that my *saves* are somehow destroying the **defaultContext** object?  If so, would it be wise of me to create a *new* defaultContext for each MR method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and further in AppDelegate.m as

```
defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
```

... this is likely AOK, since you are likely on the main thread.

> where it is used throughout the app.

... this is less OK, since "throughout the app" implies that are you possibly on *not* the main thread.

You probably want to use `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]` in specific places.

Take a look at what `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]` and `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]` do in MagicalRecord (type that out in your code, and cmd-click on it for a fast way to find it). You'll see that `MR_contextForCurrentThread` uses the defaultContext *on the main thread*, and creates a new context parented to the defaultContext on other threads.

Comment: That makes sense... according to Crashlytics, I'm *not* on the main thread when this happens; I assume that when the app loads (AppDelegate.m) it *is* on the main thread.  So would the best way to do this is determine which thread I'm on, and if not the main thread, set it to use MR_contextForCurrentThread?